# iOS 11 | Mobile | JavaScript | Touch events don't always fire

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, ios11, touch-event

Good evening everyone,

I have found an issue on iOS 11. I've checked the following devices: iPhone 8 (11) and 6 (11.2). It was fine on an iPhone 7 (10).

**Replicate:**

- Go to a website where you are able to scroll vertically e.g. Google search.
- Add the script below (or something similar) via console.
- Scroll down the page and check the console for logs. It becomes unresponsive and only seems to work near the top of the page.

  ```
  function touchHandler(type) { 
      console.log(type);
  }

  ['start', 'move', 'end'].forEach((type) => { 
      document.body.addEventListener(`touch${type}`, ({ type }) => {      
          touchHandler(type);   
      });
  });
  ```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Let me know if a live example is required. I could replicate it easily with the above.

I hope this makes sense (I'm half asleep).

**Edit:**

On further investigation I have found out this extra information:

- Touch events won't fire constantly (unlike older iOS versions).
- The event has to end before they re-fire.

Try dragging twice. It won't output a log the second time. If you wait a couple seconds the touch event will work again.

**Is there a way to get the touch events to work constantly on iOS 11?**

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation I have found out this extra information:

Touch events won't fire constantly (unlike older iOS versions).
The event has to end before they re-fire.
Try dragging twice. It won't output a log the second time. If you wait a couple seconds the touch event will work again.

Comment: Although I added this information to the question it is not the answer I require. I would like a solution. Amended above.